# React consume Graphql API - Network request

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have an app in React Native that consume an Graphql API, but when I try to make the API call, I am receiving the Error "[Network error]: TypeError: Network request failed"

**The component structure is:**

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';


const GET_RECIPES = gql`
query consultarReceitas{
  recipe{
    id
    title
    author
    link
    category
    subcategory
    ingredients{
      name
      quantity
      measure
      observation
    }
  }
}
`
export default function RecipeList({ navigation, route }) {
  return (
    <View>
    <Query query={GET_RECIPES}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        if(loading){
          return <Text>Loading</Text>
        }
        if(error){
          return <Text>Erro: {error.toString()}</Text>
        }
        console.log(data)
        return (
        <ul>
          {
            data.recipe.map((r) => {
            return <Text>{r.title}</Text>
            })
          }
        </ul>
        )
      }}
    </Query>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Can anyone help me to discovery how to solve it?

Comment: I suppose that the endpoint works with postman. Did u have problems with both android and ios ?

Comment: Yes, it is working with Postman, I have just tested the expo client (android).

Comment: sorry for the delay, you are using localhost:port or using ip?. With android localhost usually not work and you should put your host ip directly